# How to find out which ads were clicked with Google Adsense?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

If you are running Adsense (and Google Analytics) on your site, it is possible to find out which ads people clicked on?

That would be very useful marketing information about what products people are interested in buying...

Answer (score 5):

Yes it would be useful but Google will not tell you what ads were displayed when they were clicked on because then you could find out their payouts and advertisers CPC.

Your best option is to setup AdSense to track each type of ad and it's location on your website. So you'll at least know which are the more profitable spaces on your website.